# Is there a way that i can white-list inbound traffic for instance running on AWS other than security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, whitelist, aws-security-group

Is there any way that i can white-list ip's inbound traffic for the instance running in AWS and with an ELB other than doing it in Security Groups?? As because my inbound rules limit is over.

Please Advice.

Comment: This may be better on one of the other stack exchange site. I think this is off topic for stack overflow. You may be able to use IPTables.

Comment: What is the purpose of whitelisting? To block malicious users or for access control?

Comment: @Wes - Any suggestions on which sites it could work??

Comment: @Ashan - Basically white-listing is done for the SMTP Port [25] as specific ip needs to ping the SMTP server which is running on Windows 10. Here we can take both, To block the users and for access control . Thank You!

Comment: @Teja maybe serverfault maybe webapps Its an administrative difficulty rather than a code difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. It's a service called [Amazon WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/).

The gist of WAF is you have an ACL which consists of rules, these can be any of the following:

- Size constraint conditions
- IP match conditions
- ...

In each rule you can add IP ranges (both manually and programmatically) which you can match or block based on your own conditions

This ACL is then applied to an ELB and can hold a LOT of rules.
There's a limit of 100 rules with a limit of 10,000 IP address ranges.

AWS WAF can be deployed either on AWS CloudFront or on ALB (The new type of ELB)

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate. But here in WAF i can see the firewall is only for [web applications] i.e for HTTP and HTTPS ports,but I need it for SMTP port [25] as we have stmp server inside the instances[windows]with ELB and white-listed ip's need to ping to the server for test mail. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are managing the instances in same vpc/subnets, you can use the [NACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) for white-listing and blacklisting of IP ranges.

If not, then the security group rules limit is the constraint.